# What must be installed for WMPLib to work with C#?

Tags: c#, prerequisites, wmplib

I currently have a project using WMPLib that I'm using to play multiple sounds at the same time. I am not using the ActiveX component. Everything is working great on my machine.

Before I send this over to the ops team to push out to all our users, I'd like to make sure that it's going to work on all our client machines. Is there any documentation out there for the prerequisites to getting WMPLib to work, besides the obvious that the machine needs to be running Windows?

Answer (score 1):

One prerequisite that I think you should consider is the one that the user should have Windows Media Player installed from `Turn Windows features on or off>Media Features>Windows Media Player`.

[image]